# Android trying to resolve frameworks that I deleted

Tags: android, maven, gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to make a library for private distribution.

I have set up artifactory and published it to there.

The problem is when i go to include in other project, I get a bunch of errors

`ERROR: Failed to resolve: some-old-framework:some-old-sub-framework:unspecified`

The `some-old-framework` was some modules that I had added by importing aar to the project, however when I switched to use artifactory I made all these old frameworks also use artifactory, and i deleted the old modules out of my app and included them with gradle instead.

So how are all these old frameworks still showing up? When i look at my generated pom files none of the `some-old-framework` are listed in any of them.

Where might these frameworks being included from and how can i get rid of them so its stops trying to resolve them?

Comment: check you app module for old module,  check your gradle.settings for the same

Answer (score 0):

One of my submodules still had one of the other submodules listed in its `gradle.settings` after removing that and rebuilding, i was left with only one error and it was just:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: :unspecified:
```

After a couple hours of trying things, I hit load/unload module in each of my projects and noticed some of them listed duplicate modules and some still listed some of the old submodules. After unloading all duplicated and old modules, everything worked as expected.